# 20.04 breaks various 18.04 features - Wake from Suspend -Colour themes - Alt+Tab - Krusader - Double Commander

Tags: boot, suspend, themes, ubuntu-studio, krusader

Ubuntu Studio (Xubuntu / XFCE desktop)
Upgraded to 20.04, from 18.04 yesterday, and so far, am saddened by how much basic usability stuff is smashed.
Wish I hadn't done it. I should have known better!

I am running stock Dell Optiplex 9020, 8gb ram, platter HDD.

Various problems below -- should I start independent threads?

- PC Doesn't wake properly from suspend (brings me to login screen - can't see my password being entered in the pwd field,
  and when I type it and press enter, this does nothing (repeated attempts).
  Opening a TTY, I get a blinking underscore, and cannot enter any text - seems to glitch to a halt.
- I am a dark theme user, and the upgrade has  messed up colour themes in various places and applications
  (esp. file browsers, esp Krusader which makes basic stuff hard to use)
  eg. finding I can't run dark mode AND use krusader,
  because Krusader colours become unusable
  (Can't see the menu items because they are completely black.
  ...
  Can no longer rename files because renaming makes text bg completely black, so I can't see what I'm typing).
- Dark theme - alt+tab (scroll through items in a list view) no longer has a highlight,
  so I no longer know where in the list of applications I have scrolled to (very annoying I use this constantly).
- Double Commander has a markedly slower response time in use.
- graphics (drivers) a bit glitchy (on startup, takes a while to sort itself out)
- slower boot / load and start-up times
- slower response times (obvious one is opening the whisker menu is noticably slower, esp. after boot)
- grub only allowing low-latency version of ubuntu - and not standard version, etc.
- On upgrade, audio output did not work. I had to remove packages per a forum search,  sudo apt-get remove timidity.   This worked for a day, but updating again and no sound again  ):

So, essentially, for all intents and purposes, 20.04 has broken dark theme for practical use, as far as I'm concerned, and various other basic things.

Any help on any of this much appreciated.
Although it's partly just me complaining ):

Comment: Did you upgrade from a running 18.04 system, or do a clean install? I always recommend a clean install, I happen to do that just yesterday and all is fine. The themes even seem to be better than on 18.04. It is correct though that Ubuntu Studio 20.04 only seems to install the low-latency kernels, but it should be easy to install additional ones. Also, I would tag the post with Ubuntu Studio, not Xubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will change the tag. I upgraded the system (not clean install). Clean install seems a bit like a complex hassle. Maybe I will try. It just makes my heart sink, as I had a nicely functioning system.
I seem to have 2 desktop managers (mal)functioning when I try to login from suspend I have noticed. I have to login twice on a fresh power on.

Comment: It is more work to do a clean install, true. But you can be sure that you have a working system afterwards. And also it's a good occasion to do some clean-up, install only the stuff you really need, and get more up-to-date versions of the software you do use. I recommend having a spreadsheet in which you note all the packages you install after the initial setup, as well as any custom configuration. Makes it easier to re-do everything on the next upgrade.

Comment: Thanks again Sebastian. 
Good advice for a newbie.
I hear what you're saying, but I've spent enough time w' PCs to know to keep them clean + only install stuff I'm going to use fr reliable trusted sources.
The note-taking of pkg installs is something I definitely do. 
I have several docs related to how I have put my system together so I can reconstruct it -
(based on having to do fresh installs and new builds of 18.04 in the past) --   
It's all something I didn't plan to do right now to my MAIN SYSTEM!
....which was working fine- I was happy with it, it suited my workflow just fine.

Comment: It's the 1st time I've upgraded an Ubuntu OS to a new version, and I thought it would be a smoother ride. 
I should have known better than to get straight on board with the new thing, really. 
The thing with Ubtu Studio is that it is likely to be utilised by people who are not necessarily computer obsessives,
not devs, not that Linux-literate. Probably converts from Apple, even. They just want to use it, not spend time messing around with bash commands in the console, 
reconstructing their entire system whenever there is an OS upgrade because it breaks heaps of stuff, and screws lots up.

Comment: Anyway... 
Get what you pay for, I guess (:

I appreciate the information. It is stuff that people have told me on other ubuntu forums when I was first getting into this, 
and it is very good advice.